# Doctrine2 - need some help modifying working dql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following dql SELECT query, which works:

```
SELECT q AS question, AVG(r.score) AS average
  FROM MyBundle:Question q
  JOIN q.ratings r
  WHERE q.deleted IS NULL
  GROUP BY q.id
  ORDER BY q.id ASC
```

What I'd like to do is make it return 0 if `AVG(r.score)` is either 0 or null.  I'm just not sure how to do it.  Is it possible to do something like:

```
SELECT q AS question, (AVG(r.score) OR 0) AS average FROM....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my (INNER) JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN gave me the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause, you must use `HAVING` instead. That should do the trick:

```
SELECT q AS question, AVG(r.score) AS average
  FROM MyBundle:Question q
  JOIN q.ratings r
  WHERE q.deleted IS NULL
  GROUP BY q.id
  HAVING average IN (0, NULL)
  ORDER BY q.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an alternative of mysql [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to a doctrine query builder. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099412/ifnull-in-symfony2-doctrine-query-builder).