# What is the difference between IFNULL and COALESCE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULL, 'Replaces the NULL')
--> Replaces the NULL

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'Replaces the NULL')
--> Replaces the NULL
```

In both clauses the main difference is argument passing. For `IFNULL` it's two parameters and for `COALESCE` it's multiple parameters. So except that, do we have any other difference between these two?

And how it differs in MS SQL?

Comment: `IFNULL` checks a single argument. `COALESCE` works with N arguments. `COALESCE` is useful when you have unknown number of values that you want to check. `IFNULL` is useful when you select columns and know that it can be null but you want to represent it with a different value. Therefore, the two functions are *vastly* different. As for MSSQL difference - google can help you, you can obtain this information much quickly by doing your own research.

Comment: @N.B., Referring to *"`IFNULL` checks a single argument. `COALESCE` works with `N` arguments. "*, for the case where `N = 2`, both works. Which will you use then?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The main difference between the two is that `IFNULL` function takes two arguments and returns the first one if it's not `NULL` or the second if the first one is `NULL`.

`COALESCE` function can take two or more parameters and returns the first non-NULL parameter, or `NULL` if all parameters are null, for example:

```
SELECT IFNULL('some value', 'some other value');
-> returns 'some value'

SELECT IFNULL(NULL,'some other value');
-> returns 'some other value'

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 'some other value');
-> returns 'some other value' - equivalent of the IFNULL function

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 'some value', 'some other value');
-> returns 'some value'

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'first non-null value');
-> returns 'first non-null value'
```

**UPDATE:** MSSQL does stricter type and parameter checking. Further, it doesn't have `IFNULL` function but instead `ISNULL` function, which needs to know the types of the arguments.  Therefore:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL);
-> results in an error

SELECT ISNULL(NULL, CAST(NULL as VARCHAR));
-> returns NULL
```

Also `COALESCE` function in MSSQL requires at least one parameter to be non-null, therefore:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
-> results in an error

SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'first non-null value');
-> returns 'first non-null value'
```

Comment: One nitpick: you don't need at least one non-null value in `COALESCE` in MSSQL. You cannot use only `NULL` constants but all values can be null(f.e. in a query). So this is ok: `COALESCE(NULL, ValueWhichIsNULL)`. Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f5c7/2/0

Answer (score 41):

#### Pros of `COALESCE`

- **`COALESCE` is SQL-standard function**.

  While `IFNULL` is MySQL-specific and its equivalent in MSSQL (`ISNULL`) is MSSQL-specific.
- **`COALESCE` can work with two or more arguments** (in fact, it can work with a single argument, but is pretty useless in this case: `COALESCE(a)`≡`a`).

  While MySQL's `IFNULL` and MSSQL's `ISNULL` are limited versions of `COALESCE` that can work with two arguments only.

#### Cons of `COALESCE`

- Per [Transact SQL documentation](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql), `COALESCE` is just a syntax sugar for `CASE` and **can evaluate its arguments more that once**. In more detail: `COALESCE(a1, a2, …, aN)`≡`CASE WHEN (a1 IS NOT NULL) THEN a1 WHEN (a2 IS NOT NULL) THEN a2 ELSE aN END`. This greatly reduces the usefulness of `COALESCE` in MSSQL.

  On the other hand, `ISNULL` in MSSQL is a normal function and never evaluates its arguments more than once. `COALESCE` in MySQL and PostgreSQL neither evaluates its arguments more than once.
- At this point of time, I don't know how exactly SQL-standards define `COALESCE`.

  As we see from previous point, actual implementations in RDBMS vary: some (e.g. MSSQL) make `COALESCE` to evaluate its arguments more than once, some (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL) — don't.

  c-treeACE, which [claims it's `COALESCE` implementation is SQL-92 compatible](//docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#33405.htm), says: "This function is not allowed in a GROUP BY clause. Arguments to this function cannot be query expressions." I don't know whether these restrictions are really within SQL-standard; most actual implementations of `COALESCE` (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL) don't have such restrictions. `IFNULL`/`ISNULL`, as normal functions, don't have such restrictions either.

#### Resume

Unless you face specific restrictions of `COALESCE` in specific RDBMS, I'd recommend to **always use `COALESCE`** as more standard and more generic.

The exceptions are:

- Long-calculated expressions or expressions with side effects in MSSQL (as, per documentation, `COALESCE(expr1, …)` may evaluate `expr1` twice).
- Usage within `GROUP BY` or with query expressions in c-treeACE.
- Etc.

Comment: There may be also some technical database/driver-specific differences. For example ODBC driver for MySQL causes `IFNULL(datetime1, datetime2)` expression to return `System.DateTime`, but `COALESCE(datetime1, datetime2)` — `System.Byte[]` (at least in some versions, though it looks like a bug, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Differences in **SQL-Server**:

- There is no `IFNULL()` function but a similar `ISNULL()`
- `ISNULL` takes only 2 parameters whereas COALESCE takes variable number of parameters
- `COALESCE` is based on the ANSI SQL standard whereas `ISNULL` is a proprietary TSQL function
- Validations for `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` is also different. For example, `NULL` value for `ISNULL` is converted to int, whereas for `COAELSCE` you have to provide a type. Ex:

  - `ISNULL(NULL,NULL)` : is int.
  - `COALESCE(NULL,NULL)` : will throw an error.
  - `COALESCE(CAST(NULL as int),NULL)` : is valid and returns int.
- Data type determination of the resulting expression – `ISNULL` uses the first parameter type, `COALESCE` follows the `CASE` expression rules and returns type of value with highest precedence.

Comment: You are wrong.  `COALESCE(NULL, NULL)` will not throw an error - it will return `NULL`.  Further, the OP is asking about `IFNULL` function, not `ISNULL` - please read the question carefully. Oh, and `NULL` is never converted to an `int`.

Comment: @AleksG praba is answering about SQL-Server, where `COALESCE(NULL,NULL)` will indeed throw an error: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19759)

Comment: @ypercube Then he needs to make it clear in his answer.  The OP's question's title is _What is the difference bewteen ifnull and coalesce in mysql?_ - do you see sql-server there?

Comment: @AleksG I see an `[sql-server]` tag and the last question: *"And how it differs in MSSql."* But you are right, the answerer needs to clarify that the answer applies to SQL-Server only.

Comment: @praba AleksG is right.In MySql COALESCE(NULL,NULL) is not throwing any error.

Answer (score 1):

`ifnull` can only replace a null value of the first parameter. Whereas `coalesce` can replace any value with another value. With `coalesce` in standard SQL you can have many parameters transforming many values.

EDIT the example according to comments below.

Example: `coalesce(null, null, null, 'b*', null, 'null*')`
returns 'b*' and it is not possible to do with `ifnull`.

Comment: Refering to which rdbms you have given above example.The result is "b" not "b*" in MySql

Comment: OK, removed my comments.

Answer (score -1):

This db2 SQL will not work with COALESE, I will not see any rows retrieved.
Since I used IFNULL it is working as expected

```
select a.mbitno ,a.mbstqt,ifnull(b.apr,0)
from
( 
    select mmstcd,mbstat,mbfaci,mbwhlo,mbitno,mbstqt,MBALQT from libl.mitbal  inner join libl.mitmas on 
    mmcono=mbcono and mmitno=mbitno 
    where mbcono=200 and mbstat in ('20','50') and mmstcd>0  
)  
as a left join 
(
    select mlfaci,mlwhlo,mlitno,mlstas,sum(mlstqt) as APR from libl.mitloc where mlcono=200 and mlstas='2'
    group by mlfaci,mlwhlo,mlitno,mlstas
) 
b on b.mlfaci=a.mbfaci and b.mlwhlo=a.mbwhlo and b.mlitno=a.mbitno 
where a.mbitno in 'GWF0240XPEC' and a.mbstqt>0 and a.mbstqt<>ifnull(b.apr,0)
```