# MySQL Sum() multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of student scorecard.
here is the table,

```
subject  | mark1 | mark2 | mark3 |......|markn
stud1    | 99    | 87    | 92    |      | 46
stud2    |....................................
  .
  .
studn    |....................................|
```

Now, I need to sum it for each student of total marks. I got it by using `sum(mark1+mark2+...+markn) group by stud`. I want to know how to sum it without adding each column name,it will be huge when in case up to marks26. so could anyone know how to fix it.

Comment: @user2727841 he did, `sum(mark....`

Comment: Read this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232181/SQL-Pivot-with-Grand-Total-Column-and-Row[1]

Comment: @SATSON, great article on for MS Sql on `Pivot`, its a shame the OP needs mysql help.

Answer (score 128):

```
SELECT student, (SUM(mark1)+SUM(mark2)+SUM(mark3)....+SUM(markn)) AS Total
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY student
```

Comment: `I want to know how to sum it without adding each column name` quoted.

Comment: @Maulik patel, Instead of that (sum(mark1)+sum(mark2)....+sum(markn)), It's better to follow sum(mark1+mark2+...+markn).

Comment: this could be useful when handling NULL fields http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602271/how-do-i-get-sum-function-in-mysql-to-return-0-if-no-values-are-found

Comment: Yes use when fields is null

Comment: I agree with @Rashi - using `COALESCE` is a good pattern. But I wonder why the `+` operator doesn't ignore NULL values by default, like `SUM` does...

Answer (score 35):

Another way of doing this is by generating the select query. Play with this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a60ae1/23).

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', group_concat(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR '+'), ' FROM scorecard') 
FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (select database()) 
AND   `TABLE_NAME`   = 'scorecard'
AND   `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'mark%';
```

The query above will generate another query that will do the selecting for you.

1. Run the above query.
2. Get the result and run that resulting query.

Sample result:

```
SELECT mark1+mark2+mark3 FROM scorecard
```

You won't have to manually add all the columns anymore.

Comment: This above query will be more helpful to retrieve the column names which are required from huge column names. But it needs additional query to sum up the values from the first query. If, it is simple and single it could be better for every one who are looking like this and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 23):

If any of your `markn` columns are "AllowNull" then you will need to do a little extra to insure the correct result is returned, this is because 1 NULL value will result in a NULL total.

This is what i would consider to be the correct answer.

```sql
SUM(IFNULL(`mark1`, 0) + IFNULL(`mark2`, 0) + IFNULL(`mark3`, 0)) AS `total_marks`
```

[IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) will return the 2nd parameter if the 1st is NULL.
[COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) could be used but i prefer to only use it if it is required.
See [What is the difference bewteen ifnull and coalesce in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528468/what-is-the-difference-bewteen-ifnull-and-coalesce-in-mysql/43205713)

[SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)-ing the entire calculation is tidier than SUM-ing each column individually.

```
SELECT `student`, SUM(IFNULL(`mark1`, 0) + IFNULL(`mark2`, 0) + IFNULL(`mark3`, 0)) AS `total_marks` 
FROM student_scorecard
GROUP BY `student`
```

> i want to know how to sum it without adding each column name,it will be huge when in case up to marks26

To generate and execute this statement dynamically in sql you would need to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table to create a query string then execute it using a prepared statement saved in a variable.

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT `student`, SUM(IFNULL(`', group_concat(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR '`, 0) + IFNULL(`'), '`, 0) AS `total_marks` FROM `student_scorecard` GROUP BY `student`') 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = (select DATABASE()) 
AND `TABLE_NAME`   = 'student_scorecard'
AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'mark%'
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22369767/2273611


# insert statement sql into a variable
INTO @statement_var;

#prepare the statement string
PREPARE stmt_name FROM @statement_var;

#execute the prepared statement/query
EXECUTE stmt_name;

# release statement
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
```

Comment: Just a quick note, if you follow this and try it out in PHPMYADMIN, it will predict an error, but still work.  Just hit the `GO` button.

Answer (score 9):

SELECT student, SUM(mark1+mark2+mark3+....+markn) AS Total FROM your_table

Comment: like @TerranJones said above, what if any of them becomes NULL?

Comment: it doesn't effect the end result

Comment: pretty sure it does, tho. any addition with NULL results in NULL.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is there's no great way to do this given the design you have. Here's a related question on the topic: [Sum values of a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179207/sum-values-of-a-single-row)

If you normalized your schema and created a separate table called "Marks" which had a subject_id and a mark column this would allow you to take advantage of the SUM function as intended by a relational model.

Then your query would be

```
SELECT subject, SUM(mark) total 
FROM Subjects s 
  INNER JOIN Marks m ON m.subject_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: If it is normalized schema,then i think it would be better to follow the way which you explained above. But it's not possible in all cases. Everything are not normalized according to me and no need to normalize for run-time requirement.If i am  wrong sorry me.Thanks @Jon Todd.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple way to do sum of columns

```
SELECT sum(IF(day_1 = 1,1,0)+IF(day_3 = 1,1,0)++IF(day_4 = 1,1,0)) from attendence WHERE class_period_id='1' and student_id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the database structure such that all subject rows become a column variable (like spreadsheet). This makes such analysis much easier

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ((max(assignment1))+(max(assignment2))+(max(assignment3))-(min(assignment1))+(min(assignment2))+(min(assignment3)))from box_scores;
```