# Sum values in multidimensional array (selecting multiple columns with multiple rows)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Let's say I have 5 different columns, `a, b, c, d, e`, and I'm selecting multiple rows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM posts WHERE submitter='$user'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $ratings[] = $row; 
}
```

**Example:**

The user has 3 posts, so it'll select 3 rows in the query.

I want to sum all of the rows' values for `a` (and the rest of course).

e.g.

`row 1` `a` value = 4

`row 2` `a` value = 10

`row 3` `a` value = 1

So I need to sum all of those to get 15.

---

I know to use `array_sum($ratings)` to find the sum of the array but only if you select one column (`a`) which can have multiple rows, but this is multi-dimensional right due to multiple column values being selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Sum() multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369336/mysql-sum-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`sum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) in your query:

```
select sum(a)
     , sum(b)
     , sum(c)
     , sum(d)
     , sum(e)
from posts
where submitter = '$user'
```

Comment: What will be stored in the `$ratings` array?

Comment: I think you read that wrong.. -What- will be stored in there I mean?

Comment: @frosty: sorry, there will be an array of sums for each column, you can `var_dump` result to see it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's still producing a multi-dimensional array tho. `array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["sum(a)"]=> string(2) "22"` --- how do I retrieve the "22"?

Comment: @frosty: well, just use `$ratings = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of the whole `while` loop. Then you can get `22` with `$ratings["sum(a)"]`.

Comment: Ahh, so it sums all the rows into "one" row kinda?

Comment: @frosty: yes, it is the main idea here.

Comment: Yes, just saw your edit. Was trying $row[0] and $row['a'] but wasn't working, $row['sum(a)'] works though

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` aggregate function and `group by` in MySQL.

```
SELECT
  submitter,
  count(a) as rating
FROM posts
WHERE submitter='$user'
GROUP BY submitter
```

A a result you will get something like that:

```
some submitter, 3
another submitter, 10
one more submitter, 1
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: ty for the answer, I was able to get it working with the other answer tho