# How to perform single sql query to sum columns from grouped results in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models - `Parent` and `Params`, where `parent has_many params`

Currently, my methods looks like (not that it is under Parent class):

```
def total_sum
  params.select(
    'params.*, (
      SUM(mono_volume_annular) + 
      SUM(day_volume_annular) + 
      SUM(night_volume_annular) + 
      SUM(exclusive_volume_annular)
    ) AS summed_volume_annular'
  ).group('params.id').sum(&:summed_volume_annular)
end
```

How can I improve this SQL query to get rid of `.sum(&:summed_volume_annular)` method call?

If I'll try to summarize it without converting `:summed_volume_annular` to proc, I'll get this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "summed_volume_annular" does not exist`

An interesting note - If I'll try to save the result of this query

```
params.select('(
    SUM(mono_volume_annular) + 
    SUM(day_volume_annular) + 
    SUM(night_volume_annular) + 
    SUM(exclusive_volume_annular)
  ) AS summed_volume_annular'
)
```

I will get this object `[#<Parameter:0x00000009f1c7d8 id: nil>]`

Strange that `summed_volume_annular` is absent...

Comment: if you are using `group('params.id')` then why you are using `sum` inside query because your group always have one record

Comment: @VishalJAIN because I need to summarize multiple columns into one. I called it `summed_volume_annular`. I use multiple sum() functions because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369336/mysql-sum-multiple-columns/22369527#comment42560192_22369527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def total_sum
  columns_to_sum = %w(mono_volume_annular day_volume_annular night_volume_annular
                      exclusive_volume_annular)
  sum = columns_to_sum.map{ |col| "COALESCE(#{col}, 0)" }.join(' + ')
  Params.sum(sum)
end
```

Comment: I changed the example, hope it helps :)

Comment: it almost what I was looking for. Instead of summarizing all of the `Params` records I needed to summarize only associated with `parent` object. I changed `Params` to `params` and thats it. Thanks!