# Unknown column 'result1' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

i am trying to sum the values for result1 and result2 but it comes up with unknown column result1. Can someone please assist. What am i doing wrong.

```
SELECT *
      ,case when event1 = '100mh' then 25.4347*power(sum(18.00-10.40),1.81) end as result1
      ,case when event2 = 'highjump' then 9.4347*power(sum(14.00-145),1.835) end as result2
      ,SUM(result1 + result2 )as total
from heptathlon 
group by athlete_id
```

Comment: You should mark off past questions that were resolved before posting new ones, IMHO.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369336/mysql-sum-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*, sum(t.result1 + t.result2) AS total
  FROM (  SELECT b.*,
                 CASE
                    WHEN b.event1 = '100mh'
                    THEN
                       25.4347 * POWER (SUM (18.00 - 10.40), 1.81)
                 END
                    AS result1,
                 CASE
                    WHEN b.event2 = 'highjump'
                    THEN
                       9.4347 * POWER (SUM (14.00 - 145), 1.835)
                 END
                    AS result2
            FROM heptathlon b
        GROUP BY b.athlete_id) t
```

Comment: Your solution results in the following error. FUNCTION framework.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @Webjunkie sum keyword was missing.. Check now. It should work in Mysql however the earlier one will also work fine in oracle.

Comment: your solution worked. I just needed to remove the unwanted spaces. Thanks