# MySQL SUM of row data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to calculate a **summary** of **row** datas in MySQL with PHP. For example, if I'd like to check xyz's sum: **4+1+9+3**

I would like to echo the sum.

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| username   | valu1 | valu2 | valu3 | valu4 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| bozai.akos |     3 |     0 |     0 |     3 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| xzy.xyz    |     4 |     1 |     9 |     3 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| abc.abc    |     3 |     2 |     7 |     5 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Sum() multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369336/mysql-sum-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want an addition?

```
select t.*,
    valu1 + valu2 + valu3 + valu4 as res
from mytable t
```

Note that if any of the column has a `null` value, the addition returns a `null` value as well. You might want to avoid that, so:

```
select t.*,
    coalesce(valu1, 0) + coalesce(valu2, 0) + coalesce(valu3, 0) + coalesce(valu4, 0) as res
from mytable t
```