# How to check if database values are null?

Tags: php, sql, database, variables, null

I'm new to PHP/SQL and very confused.

In my SQL database, I have the following values for a user:

[image: values]

In my PHP script, echoing these values gives me 0.

Query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '{$email}'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

I specify the email linked to the above user in the database. I get the desired row as a result (user ID 13 and these null values). Still, the code gets inside this if statement:

```
if (!empty($row['first_name']) && !empty($row['last_name']) && 
!empty($row['age']) && !empty($row['picture_path'])) {
    echo "inside";
}
```

Echoing the values themselves gave me 0 instead of null. Why? And how can I properly check for empty/null?

Thanks loads.

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: if you want to check in php, you can use [is_null()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php), otherwise you want to use mysql you can use [ifnull, COALESCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528468/what-is-the-difference-bewteen-ifnull-and-coalesce-in-mysql)

Comment: Doesn't !empty check, for empty and null values?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I am correctly retrieving this exact row inside my database. The problem lies when I evaluate the values and get 0 instead of null. I just edited my question to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: `$var = is_null($row['name']) ? 'Null' : $row['name']; echo $var;`

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a certain string if a certain value is null using `COALESCE()` function. See below:

```
"SELECT 
       COALESCE(user_id,'null')user_id,
       COALESCE(first_name,'null')first_name,
       COALESCE(middle_name,'null')middle_name,
       COALESCE(last_name,'null')last_name,
       COALESCE(rs_status,'null')rs_status,
       COALESCE(age,'null')age,
       COALESCE(town,'null')town,
       COALESCE(phone,'null')phone,
       COALESCE(picture_path,'null')picture_path
 FROM user 
WHERE email = '{$email}'"
```

Comment: I see, so I would test against that assigned string. It's clever, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: That's the simpler way that I know.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `empty('0')` returns `true`; to test for null use `is_null($var)`.

Not intuitive but that's what it is.