# MySQL - JOIN a OR b

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a `TABLE a` in which a `COLUMN data` is the one to **join** on for 2 other tables (`TABLE b` and `TABLE c`) because I want to get a `COLUMN info` in `b` or `c`.
The thing is `a.data` will match **only** with `b.data` **or only** with `c.data`.

- How can I get `b.info` or `c.info` based on `a` ?

#### How far did I try:

After many attempts with obviously wrong syntax, the best I did was in 2 queries:

```
SELECT b.info FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.data = b.data
SELECT c.info FROM a INNER JOIN c ON a.data = c.data
```

I would like to achieve something that could look like this:

```
SELECT alias.info FROM a INNER JOIN (b OR c) AS alias ON a.data = alias.data
```

#### Why do I want to do this

Actually I can get the data I want and work with it using PHP. But I am making a huge process (unrelated to my question) instead of a good query and the page takes too much time to load.

Comment: use UNION or LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join to both of the `b` and `c` tables, then use whichever `info` field is not `NULL`:

```
select coalesce(b.info, c.info) info
from a
  left join b on a.data = b.data
  left join c on a.data = c.data
```

Comment: Reading the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528468/what-is-the-difference-bewteen-ifnull-and-coalesce-in-mysql) I will use your answer as I didn't mentionned `TABLE d` in my question. +1 for explaining your answer, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(b.info,c.info) AS info
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.data = b.data
    LEFT JOIN c ON a.data = c.data
```

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is guaranteed to be UNIQUE in tables `b` and `c`

We can use *outer join* to attempt to get matching row from each of the tables, and then use expression in the SELECT list to test whether we got a matching row.  For example:

```
SELECT a.data
     , IF(b.data IS NULL,IF(c.data IS NULL,NULL,'c'),'b') AS info_src
     , IF(b.data IS NULL,c.info,b.info) AS b_or_c_info
  FROM a
  LEFT
  JOIN b 
    ON b.data = a.data
  LEFT
  JOIN c
    ON c.data = a.data
```

If we find a matching row in `b`, then `b.data` is guaranteed to be non-NULL.  We know the value is non-NULL because it satisfied an equality (`=`) comparison.

Note that `IF` is MySQL specific syntax. A more portable ANSI-standards compliant version

```
       CASE
         WHEN b.data IS NULL
         THEN c.info
         ELSE b.info
       END  AS b_or_c_info
```

Comment: Thanks it works well too. I am aware that `IF` is MySQL specific but I don't completely understand the query. Is the `info_src` important ?
Thank you for your answer

Comment: The `info_src` column isn't required. It's just an additional column in the result. We frequently include a discriminator column, like `info_src` in this example. to tell us which row source the value of `info` is from... b, c or neither. In some cases, we want to know that, and including a discriminator column is a convenient way to communicate that information back  If it's not important to know which table `b_or_c_info` value came from, then `info_src` column is not important. (I included it in the example because in some use cases, it is important to know the source.)